# Derive the ideal shape for a dome and a cylindrical arch

Tags: variational-calculus, statics

A catenary is the ideal shape for an arch whose job is to support its own weight. First, would this be true for a surface of revolution about a vertical axis through the lowest point, i.e. would a catenary describe the radial cross-section for a dome as well? Second, would the catenary describe the ideal radial cross-section for a bundt cake shape,$^1$ i.e. an arch rotated about a [vertical] axis outside the structure such that the surface would cover a donut?

Unless there's a convincing argument that it's not needed, a great answer would use radial symmetry to reduce the problem to one radial coordinate and then use calculus of variations to either show it's identical to the same step in deriving the 1 dimensional arch's inverted catenary shape or to produce the correct answer.

[image: Smooth Bundt Cake Pan]

Note, the pan is inverted from the question I'm asking in much the same way as the cake would be inverted after baking.

$^1 \quad _\text{Semi-torus? Bundt cake pans usually have a non-minimal surface area to increase surface area, but I'm asking about the pictured smooth geometry.}$

Answer (score 0):

I will discuss the dome case.

We have: the defining characteristic of a catenary arch (in the idealized case) is that at every point along the arch the local stress is in the direction *tangent* to the arch.

The weight of the top of the arch provides the force that is necessary to keep the sides from sagging towards the center; the weight of the sides provides the force that is necessary to keep the top from sagging down.

In the case of the catenary arch: the weight per unit of length along the arch is uniform and the weight per unit along the horizontal is proportional to the slope of the arch.

In the case of the dome the determining factor is weight per unit of *surface area* of the dome, instead of weight per unit of length.

The top of the dome has much less surface area than the sides, as compared to an arch: that changes the nature of the equilibrium.

So:
A surface of revolution of the catenary curve will not be a compressive-stress-only dome.

For the purpose of illustration I give the following thought experiment:
Assume we have solved the dome problem, and we have build our dome. Divide the dome in 4 quadrants, and remove two opposite quadrants.

The resulting structure will still be in equilibrium.

That illustrates that the compressive-stress-only dome has the property that there is no tension/compression component in any horizontal plane. The equilibrium is purely a result of having the right amount of weight available at the right radial distance.

The amount of inward force generated by the sides is large compared to the amount of downward force generated by the top; the weight contribution to the compressive force increases in proportion to the circumference.

Hence:
The cross-section of the compressive-stress-only dome will be the same as the shape of a planar *arch* that is constructed in such a way that the weight per unit of *arch length* increases in direct proportion to the corresponding circumference.

So: compared to a catenary arch the cross section of a compressive-stress-only dome will be a more blunt shape.

In the case of the catenary problem we had this windfall of the solution being a well definable function: the hyperbolic cosine. It seems improbable that in the case of the compressive-stress-only dome we would be so lucky again.

I expect that pushing for a solution will require a numerical analysis approach.

You may opt to code a numerical analysis implementation for this case yourself, or you may look around for existing minimization/optimization software to crunch the numbers.

Incidentally, the reason I'm so interested in this problem is this: I have on my website an exposition of calculus of variations in which I use the case of the catenary arch as example. I've been meaning for years now to find the shape of that dome; I had already figured what weight distribution should be used.